# Extract linear regression y estimates for each pixel of raster in R

Tags: r, statistics, regression, raster

I have run a per-pixel local linear regression in R using `lm()` on a raster stack (r1) containing weekly slices of data, against 'time'.

My current regression model can extract coefficients with the $ operator, and produce a raster of that coefficient, here computes R^2:

```
time<-1:nlayers(r1) 
regression <- function(y) {    if(all(is.na(y))) { NA } else {
        m = lm(y ~ time); summary(m)$r.squared   } } 
r.r1 <- calc(r1, regression)
```

I would like the regression output raster to show relative change in y over time.
Each pixel should be the deviation from the normally expected value as a percentage,
i.e. (end − start)/mean

Start is the regression estimate for y at the start of period, end is the end of period, and mean is the mean value between these two endpoints.
So I need to extract these values of y from the regression for each pixel to produce the raster, however I am unsure how to compute this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about something like this:

```r
fl <- function(x)c(x[1], x[length(x)])
regression <- function(y) {    if(all(is.na(y))) { NA } else {
  m = lm(y ~ time); diff(fl(fitted(m)))/mean(fl(fitted(m)))   } } 
r.r1 <- calc(r1, regression)
```

In the code above, the function `fl()` returns the first and last values of a vector.  Then you can use those first and last values of the fitted values from the model to generate your calculation.